# What should be put as groupId for portal level entities like Users etc

Tags: service, entity, liferay-7

I'm creating a portal level entity without groupId column since the data will not belong to any group/site. But for a certain requirement (example given below), I notice we need to provide groupId to pull some information. My questions

1. Should we still consider having groupId column? (I think no)
2. What groupId should we use when the entity is not site/group specific

I came across this issue while trying to enable searching and integrating with asses framework on my entity (without groupId). As per tutorial, I need following as a first step

```
<finder name="G_S" return-type="Collection">
    <finder-column name="groupId" />
    <finder-column name="status" />
</finder>
```

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/enabling-assets-at-the-service-layer

Now I don't have any such column, what should I do?

Comment: Great question - unfortunately I can't answer it, but can give one hint: As of my understanding, an integration with the Asset Framework implies that your entity denotes content, and content is scoped to a site in Liferay. To work around this, you could associate your content with the Global site, thus share it among all sites - that would still "pollute" your entity with a groupId that you don't need, but it's what comes with the Asset Framework integration. We'll see if someone has an actual answer, not just a description of their/my understanding.

Comment: @OlafKock Thanks for taking time to respond. I think " Asset Framework implies that your entity denotes content" is not true. Think about Users and Organizations, they are at portal/instance level. They are integrated with asset framework, you can do all the stuff you can do with contents, search, tag etc. I'm building something similar. Users are searchable in Search Portlet, they can be used in AssetPublisher etc. I want my entity to behave same. I have done almost all, but to make it searchable as per tutorial it seems like I need something as mentioned in my problem

Comment: You're right that Users and Organizations are on portal/instance level. However, they're not Assets. They can be searched, tagged, categorized - yes. When you want to publish your entity in AssetPublisher, you must implement the Asset Framework - that much is right. When you only need to make it searchable & taggable, the Asset Framework is unnecessary. Then you only need the individual features that the Asset Framework happens to also include (e.g. searchability, taggability, categorizability). Implementing an Asset implies a groupID, the other features don't.

Comment: Thanks @OlafKock. Yes you are right, User doesn't appear as Asset in asset publisher but User is given some special treatment Liferay out of normal behavior as per my understanding. However, if at the moment I'm struggling with two things, I want my entity to be searchable, which currently not happening despite I observed the indexing is being done as expected. The same code works for another entity but not for the one I want to make it as Portal/instance level. The 2nd issue, if I don't integrate my entity with asset framework, it doesn't appear in the list for SearchPortlet.

Comment: I want it searchable through the SearchPortlet as well. Any idea, if I don't integrate it with asset framework, how can I make search working

Answer (score 1):

Actually I would try to encourage you *not* to think the entities are global only.

If you are in a single site situation, this works just fine as you can keep all of the entities with the site and it acts as though they are "global".

If you are in a multi-site situation, it can seem like you just want one entity shared across all of the sites.  Often times what I've found, though, is that things you want to create and use globally, often your sites will want to do something similar for a site-local application.

If you want to stay on your path, then the Global group is the way to go.  You can retrieve this using the following:

```
Group globalGroup = _groupLocalService.getFriendlyURLGroup(
    companyId, GroupConstants.GLOBAL_FRIENDLY_URL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @dnebing , this looks like a possible workaround. But why not, think about Users and Organizations, they are at the portal/instance level. They are integrated with the asset framework, you can do all the stuff you can do with the contents, search, tag etc. I'm building something similar. Users are searchable in Search Portlet, they can be used in AssetPublisher etc. I want my entity to behave same.